# Check if any element has the focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selector that selects multiple elements. I want to check if at least one of these elements has the focus.

By experimenting, I noticed that `.is(":focus")` and `.has(":focus")` didn't work when dealing with multiple elements, see below:

```
console.log( $('.text-block').is(":focus") ); // prints false
console.log( $('.text-block').has(":focus") ); // prints empty object array
console.log( $('.text-block').filter(":focus") ); // prints empty object array
console.log( $('.text-block:focus') ); // prints one element (works!)
```

as `:focus` selector seems the only way to go, my question is: how to do if my elements (`$('.text-block')`) are in a variable (like `$myElements`) ?

(Second question would be to understand why only `:focus` selector works for me.)

Comment: What do you mean by "at least one element has the focus"? You can only have focus on one single element in your document at a time, that element is `document.activeElement`

Comment: sorry, i mean if any of the elements have the focus, thanks

Comment: When are you checking when these inputs have focus? Are you using `.focus()` or are you checking in another function?

Comment: I think elclanrs was suggesting [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/): `$('.text-block').is(document.activeElement)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each element and test if has `:focus`.

```
$('.text-block').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
        console.log('This element has focus!');
    }
});
```

I tested this with some basic HTML inputs and it works: http://jsbin.com/aTaqagOz/1/ (the JSBin I worked on was working but the preview appears not to)

Maybe your elements aren't focusing correctly?

Comment: I tested it and it seemed to work in the JSBin editor but not in the preview/share mode. You might want to try in your development environment. Edit: I just tried it in mine and it appears to work, although the `focus` event isn't being fired when I focus to the element, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read here http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/ `is(":focus")` is the way to go. if it returns false that means it does not have the focus.

you can also get he focused element by `$( document.activeElement )`.

as it stated in the jquery doc it supported starting with version 1.6 I know it is a long shot but may be you have an older version.

Comment: well according to my logs, is(":focus") didn't work, check code above, selector :focus (without is()) worked though

Comment: i see because $('.text-block') returns an array i m not sure how is working for it. checks all of them, first one only last one only. you can loop by each or just check $('.text-block:focus').length

Comment: wish i could use $('.text-block:focus').length but the question, what if the elements are in a variable $textBlockElements

Comment: did you try find instead of filter. if it returns the object that means focused element is actually a sub element of the $textBlockElements if this is the case that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':focus')) {
        console.log('This element has focus!');
    }
});
```